# Storing variable products options in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I’m building part of a website where products can have various options that affect the price. Think bedding. There’s options for size, whether a headboard is required, and so on. Each option affects the cost. However, not all products will have all options.

For example, a 90cm bed with a headboard will have a different cost to a 120cm bed with no headboard.

I’ve worked with product options where there may be one option (such as t-shirt size or colour), but not complex options like this. What would be the best way to store such options in my MySQL database?

Comment: Can you show your current schema please? :) I believe one product should have the freedom to add one or more options. So you can set options initially to null and allow user to add it. You can maintain options in a table with respective prices. And when a product is customized by adding multiple options you could have a customized table that will hold each customization to a product with what option added and price. Then you do a group by product on one particular order to for a customer to sum up the total cost of that final product. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not a case of adding or subtracting from a base price when adding/removing options; a combination of options gives *the* price which is where I’m getting lost. Think of a spreadsheet, with options both across the top and down the left-hand side, and prices in the cells.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was away. please take a look at my answer explaining the comment I posted above. Feel free to comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the design I thought of and it's an assumption without seeing your schema. Hope it clarifies my comment. If this is different from what you require, please let us know. Happy to help. :)

Reference

### * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f61ab/3)

Options Table:

```
ID  NAME              ATTRIBUTE     COST
1   headboard         S             55.5
2   headboard         L             65.2
3   headboard         M             60.3
4   colour_change    (null)         20.3
5   polishing        (null)         70.2
```

Products Table:

```
ID      NAME      PCOST
1001    chair     50
1002    bed1      1200
1003    table     200
1004    cupboard  2000
1005    bed2      1000
```

Custom Table:

```
ID  PID     OID     CID
1   1002    3      (null)
2   1002    4      2
3   1003    5      (null)
4   1001    4      1
5   1004    5      (null)
```

Query 1 to get total sum of Options used for customization per product.

```
select c.pid, sum(o.cost)
from custom c
left join options o
on c.oid = o.id
group by c.pid
;
```

Results 1:

```
PID     SUM(O.COST)
1001    20.3
1002    80.6
1003    70.2
1004    70.2
```

Query 2 : Break down by product for options cost, product cost

```
-- prod cost, option cost by options and prod
select x.pid, p.name, p.pcost, x.optCost,
x.optChoices
from prod p
right join (
select c.pid, sum(o.cost) as optCost,
  group_concat(o.name, ' ') optChoices
from custom c
left join options o
on c.oid = o.id
group by c.pid) as x
on x.pid = p.id
;
```

Results 2:

```
PID     NAME         PCOST  OPTCOST     OPTCHOICES
1001    chair        50     20.3        colour_change
1002    bed1         1200   80.6        headboard ,colour_change
1003    table        200    70.2        polishing
1004    cupboard     2000   70.2        polishing
```

Query 3: Final answer

```
-- total cost
select x.pid, p.name, x.optChoices,
(p.pcost + x.optCost) totalCost
from prod p
right join (
select c.pid, sum(o.cost) as optCost,
  group_concat(o.name, ' ') optChoices
from custom c
left join options o
on c.oid = o.id
group by c.pid) as x
on x.pid = p.id
;
```

Results 3:

```
PID     NAME       OPTCHOICES                   TOTALCOST
1001    chair      colour_change                70.3
1002    bed1       headboard ,colour_change     1280.6
1003    table      polishing                    270.2
1004    cupboard   polishing                    2070.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two tables:

```
1) Product : id, name, desc, cost

2) Option_master : optionId, option_name, option_unit
3) product_option_mapping : pom_id, optionid, productid
```

Say you have two options for a product:

The product table will have :

```
id     name           desc        cost
1      Product1   Product1_desc    100
```

option_master table will have ::

```
optionId    option_name      option_unit    
1              size                cm     
2             headboard          null
```

and the product_option_mapping will have the mapping of the product and the option

Comment: So say I have two options for a product: size and headboard, how do I set the price? As a 90cm bed with headboard has a different cost to a 90cm without headboard—the options need to know about the others to set the cost correctly.